# ICMP destination unreachable

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, ip, udp

I am working on an Arch Linux machine with an ethernet interface `eth1`. I have created the interface `eth1:0` using `ifconfig` and given it a dummy hardware address (`00:01:02:03:04:05`). When I send a UDP packet to a server application running on a remote server machine, I get back the right response. But then I see an ICMP Destination Unreachable going out from the `eth1:0` interface ip address. How can I mute this ICMP message? I have tried different mac addresses and set up an arp cache on both client and server machines without success.

Appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you send the UDP packet ? could you please dump here the output from the ` ip route list` command ?

Comment: Here's the output of ip route list - default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth1 
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.100.144

Comment: add more details about your ip address (as i am understand from your question both interfaces have diefferrent ip address).

Comment: eth1 is 92.168.100.144, eth1:0 is 192.168.100.81

Comment: Is there a reason to use another interface with another MAC address for IP address in one subnet? Why you don't use the second IP address as a secondary IP address on the eth1 interface?

Answer (score -2):

Sound like you have a netmask mismatch on your sibinterface. Double check the netmask of your application server then ensure the same netmask is being used on the sub-interface of your Linux server.

Comment: They issue would not be ICMP specific.